# Recover Active Directory from a server whose motherboard is dead

Tags: backup, motherboard, data-recovery, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I had a Windows Server 2008 R2 server setup as an Active Directory. One fine day, the motherboard went dead.

After replacing the motherboard, windows boots up and says it detected hardware change and wants me to point to the backup set for recover. Unfortunately, I don't have any backups.

**My disks are perfectly ok.**

What I want to know is a way how I can get the Active Directory Recovered from these set of disks?

Answer (score 2):

How many DCs do you have in your environment? If the failed server was not the only DC in the domain, then there are other ways to restore the server.

This is not a supported method (I'd call it 'experimental') and all supported methods require making backups but you might be able to restore Active Directory Domain Services using the following procedure. If the server performed also other roles, then you might need to modify this procedure to be able to also recover the other roles.

1. Perform a fresh installation of the operating system on another machine (not touching the original disks). The machine should not have access to the original network (to avoid clients trying to authenticate), but an Internet connection might be needed (to download updates, drivers, etc.).
2. Give the machine the same name as the original server.
3. Use dcpromo.exe to create a domain with the same name as the original one.
4. Install all the updates that were installed on the original server.
5. Reboot the machine in Active Directory Restore Mode
6. Copy the contents of NTDS and SYSVOL folders from the original set of disks

Comment: +1. Plus 10 if I could give that.  
Mantra: AD servers are replaceable. All data is on other AD servers anyway.

Comment: Just be sure to check which DCs are holding FSMO roles. If the dead DC was holding the RID master role, and you seize that role away to another DC, be sure to never bring that dead DC back online.