# Windows server still reboot after recover active directory folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

**My Problem:**

Windows server is not starting up and restart when shows the win logo.

After that, i reinstall windows, reoconfigured again and execute this steps:

> 1. Perform a fresh installation of the operating system on another machine (not touching the original disks). The machine should not have
>    access to the original network (to avoid clients trying to
>    authenticate), but an Internet connection might be needed (to download
>    updates, drivers, etc.).
> 2. Give the machine the same name as the original server.
> 3. Use dcpromo.exe to create a domain with the same name as the original one.
> 4. Install all the updates that were installed on the original server.
> 5. Reboot the machine in Active Directory Restore Mode
> 6. Copy the contents of NTDS and SYSVOL folders from the original set of > disks
>
> This steps are from here:
> [Recover Active Directory from a server whose motherboard is dead](https://superuser.com/questions/840855/recover-active-directory-from-a-server-whose-motherboard-is-dead)

but when i copy the folders in the step 6 and restart windows, then crash again in the same point.

There explain how to recover the active directory using an environment with more than one server, right?

**The question:**

Copying the folders using only one server in my environment can just load my old config in AD and DC?

If i copy and then crashed again, there are some files can do a crash in my win boot? if it is true, what files and why?